# Adding numbers to specific lines in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

i want to add number 0 to begining of all string that are 13 characters long.

For example, i have texh file:

```
f8gh7rt6h4k33p
jk3le1oi0eee9
h0iec40a0jki1
sdf984lk12otra
...
```

And i want to edit this text file like this:

```
f8gh7rt6h4k33p
0jk3le1oi0eee9
0h0iec40a0jki1
sdf984lk12otra
...
```

With this regex i can find all strings that are 13 characters long `([a-zA-Z0-9]{13,13})` but i dont know how to add 0 to begining of the string to these lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.{13})$`
- Replace with: `0$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Make sure and check the Regular Expression mode search of course.

Answer (score 2):

using a lookahead (*that means "followed with" and that doesn't consume characters*):

```
\b(?=\w{13}\b)
```

replacement: `0`

or using a capture group and a reference to this capture group in the replacement string:

```
\b(\w{13})\b
```

replacement: `0\1`